# var array [rows] [columns] int Assign Dimension to an Array in Go

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm new. This is my code in GO.

```
package main

import ( "fmt" )

func main() { var number int fmt.Print("how many candidates?: ") fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &number) fmt.Print(numero)

var name []string
var nameHorse []string
var matrix [][]int

for i := 0; i < number; i++ {
    fmt.Print("name: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &name[i])
    fmt.Print("name horse: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &nameHorse[i])
    for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
        fmt.Print("how many minutes: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &matrix[i][0])
        fmt.Print("how many segs: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &matrix[i][1])
        fmt.Print("hoy many h: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &matrix[i][2])
    }
}

for i := 0; i < number; i++ {
    fmt.Print(name[i])
    fmt.Print(nameHorse[i])
    for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
        fmt.Print(matrix[i][j])
    }
    fmt.Print()
}
}

I want to define an array [2][4] but I want to define when the program is ON, like this:

fmt.Print("rows: ") fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &rows)

fmt.Print("columnas: ") fmt.Scanf("%v\n", &columns)

var matrix [rows][columns]int
```

I want to add the dimension for a project that the values will be introduced by console to the matrix.

Can somebody help me, how can I do that?

Comment: Please study https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6 ff carefully, it explains this in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [slice](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) if you don't know the size at compile time, and for multidimensional you'd want to use a loop:

```
matrix := make([][]int, rows)
for i := 0; i < rows; i++ {
    matrix[i] = make([]int, columns)
}
```